# SVN display lastest file revision by filename and file contents

Tags: svn

Is there an SVN command that can display the latest revison of a filename and also display its contents? Something like a command line:
 SVN Log config.file | Cat config.file

Windows or Linux command? The person doing the display will not be the person checking out the code. Read only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single command which will do both. Retrieving revision history information (`svn log`) and versioned item contents (`svn cat`, `svn co`, `svn export`) are separate and distinct actions.

You could use `svn log --limit 1 file; svn cat file;` in either bash (Linux) or PowerShell (Windows), but the result would be the output of two unrelated commands.

Comment: Thanks. I will leave this open to see if there are other replies