# How to search and list all SVN history of a file based on the change of a particular portion in that file

Tags: eclipse, svn

Suppose a file with 5000 line of code is committed to `SVN` more than 50 times. Somewhere in that commit history some code was added like `and subject.is_theory_practical='B'` as a part of a query.

Now I want to know who committed that file and when it was committed. In eclipse I can right click on the file and take option called `Team` and then select sub option called `Show History`, which will list all the commit history of that file - user, date, comment etc.

But I have to individually search on individual history to find the change that I'm looking for. I tried this one [SVN display latest file revision by filename and file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659986/svn-display-lastest-file-revision-by-filename-and-file-contents) but I didn't find it helpful. So is there any way that I can give the above mentioned portion of the code and conduct a search on SVN, so that I can get only the list of history where that code was either added or removed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `svn blame -v FILENAME`:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.blame.html

> Show author and revision information inline for the specified files or
>   URLs. Each line of text is annotated at the beginning with the author
>   (username) and the revision number for the last change to that line.

You can filter its output with `grep`, `sed` or similar tool.